# Get value from xml report using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, stylesheet

I have an xml which looks like below :

```
<properties>
<property>
   <id>foo.toto</id>
   <value>value1</value>
</property>
<property>
    <id>foo.toto2</id>
    <value>value2</value>
 </property>
 <property>
     <id>foo1.toto3</id>
     <value>value3</value>
 </property>
 <property>
      <id>foo2.toto4</id>
      <value>value4</value>
 </property>
 </properties>
```

I need to extract the value of property when id is equal to foo.toto2.

I tried various things like below :

```
<xsl:for-each select = "properties/property[@id='decisionservice.deployer.name']"> 
     <xsl:value-of select = "value"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Expected output is : value2.

Thank you

Comment: You need to use `id` rather that `@id`, because the `@` represents an attribute, whereas you just need to get a child node.

Comment: Hello Tim, thank you this solved my issue. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

From Tim :
You need to use id rather that @id, because the @ represents an attribute, whereas you just need to get a child node.